# Remove whitespace from both ends of a string

Tags: javascript, function

```
function lefttrim(str)
{
    function NotWhitespace(ch)
    {
        return ch != '\n' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\r' && ch != ' ' && ch != '';
    }
    var stopAt = str.length;
    for (;stopAt >= 0; --stopAt)
        if (NotWhitespace(str.charAt(stopAt)))
            break;


    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i >= stopAt; i++)
        output += str.charAt(i);
    return output;
}
```

This currently removes the whitespace on the right side of the string, but I am trying to get it to remove whitespace from both the left side and right side of the string. I am not allowed to use any built-in function for this particular exercise.

Comment: So then wouldn't you start the second loop at **stopAt** and concatenate characters until you run out of characters?  You probably need another loop to find the last non white space character.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i >= stopAt; i++)` You probably meant `<= stopAt`. And you'll need the `NotWhitespace` function to avoid the leading whitespace.

Comment: *"I am not allowed to use any built-in function."* - Then you'd best change `str.charAt(i)` to `str[i]`. @epascarello - How do you use regex without built-in functions?

Comment: To me a built in function is [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), but OP can state that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function cust_trim(str){
    String.prototype.IsWhiteSpace = function(){
        return this == '\n' || this == '\t' || this == '\r' || this == ' ' || this == '';
    }

    var i = 0;
    var j = str.length - 1;
    while(str.charAt(i).IsWhiteSpace() && i <= j) i++;

    if(i > j) return "";    // all white spaces

    while(str.charAt(j).IsWhiteSpace() && j >= 0) j--;

    var output = '';
    while( i <= j)
        output += str.charAt(i++);
    return output;
}
```